# How can I solve "crontab: your UID isn't in the passwd file. bailing out."?

Tags: ruby, docker, cron, whenever

Hi I'm using `Docker` and [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) to write cron schedule rules, but when I run `whenever --update-crontab` in my docker container this errors is showing to me.

```
crontab: your UID isn't in the passwd file.
bailing out.
[fail] Couldn't write crontab; try running `whenever' with no options to ensure your schedule file is valid.
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby:2.4.1-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron
ENV RAILS_ENV production

ENV INSTALL_PATH /app

RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH
WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH


COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install --binstubs --jobs 20 --retry 5

COPY . .
RUN chown -R nobody:nogroup /app
USER nobody

# use docker run -it --entrypoint="" demo "ls -la" to skip
EXPOSE 3000

CMD puma -C config/puma.rb
```

Docker Version: `Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be`

**My Docker compose file**

```
  chatbot_web:
    container_name: chatbot_web
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - chatbot_redis
      - chatbot_lita
    user: "1000:1000"
    build: .
    image: dpe/chatbot
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
    restart: always
```

How can I solve this?

**EDIT:**
When I use:

```
host$ docker run -it dpe/chatbot bash
container $ whenever --update-cron
[write] crontab file updated
```

Works, but when I use:

```
host$ docker exec -it chatbot_web bash                                                                                                                                                                                               
I have no name!@352c6a7500d2:/app$ whenever --update-cron
crontab: your UID isn't in the passwd file.
bailing out.
[fail] Couldn't write crontab; try running `whenever' with no options to ensure your schedule file is valid.
```

Don't Work =(

Comment: I think you are using wrong user name for scheduling job in crontab.

Comment: How can we reproduce? You didn't give any information about your host, Docker version, `Dockerfile`, or the `docker run` command. Please give us enough information to reproduce it if possible.

Comment: @AndyShinn sorry, I update my answer!

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev how I can test this?

Comment: You are right. I'm using wrong user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix I use same user in Dockerfile and docker-compose

**Dockerfile**

```
RUN chown -R nobody:nogroup /app
USER nobody
```

**Docker Compose**

```
  chatbot_web:
    user: "nobody:nogroup"
```